Great_expectations, Custom Expectation Queries Error in _validate()
I have been working with Great_expectations for a few weeks and I have just come across a problem that I cannot resolve:
I created a custom expectation which requires the metric query.multiple_columns, and using the template here:
https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/blob/0bb4542c1dcea384da2e43683676d8388181dd30/contrib/experimental/great_expectations_experimental/expectations/expect_query_to_have_no_duplicate_value_combinations.py#L22
However, after successfully getting my query to work (no more error messages), I now have when I run my checkpoint an error message indicating "_validate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'configuration'"
This is my custom expectation, the objective is to compare 2 columns and that the subtraction of these dates does not exceed 365 days, and for that I have to GROUP BY with a 3rd column (because there are duplicates) :
class ExpectQueriedMulticolumnDureeInferieurUnAn(QueryExpectation):
"""Expect the data points given primary keys via columns to be unique."""
metric_dependencies = ("query.multiple_columns",)

query = """
    SELECT bbrb."{col_3}" , MAX(bbrb."{col_1}"-bbrb."{col_2}")
    FROM "TABLE" bbrb 
    group BY bbrb."{col_3}"
    HAVING  MAX(bbrb."{col_1}"-bbrb."{col_2}") < 365
"""

success_keys = ("query", "columns")
domain_keys = ("batch_id", "row_condition", "condition_parser")
default_kwarg_values = {
    "result_format": "BASIC",
    "catch_exceptions": False,
    "meta": None,
    "columns": None,
    "query": query,
}

def _validate(
    self,
    metrics: dict,
    runtime_configuration: dict = None,
    execution_engine: ExecutionEngine = None,
) -> Union[ExpectationValidationResult, dict]:
    query_result = metrics.get("query.multiple_columns")

    query_result = [tuple(element.values()) for element in query_result]

    success = not query_result

    observed_value = query_result

    return ExpectationValidationResult(
        success=success,
        result={"observed_value": observed_value}
    )

I retrieved the exection_info in result:
        "exception_info": {
          "exception_traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/XXX/bordereaux/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/great_expectations/validator/validator.py\", line 1073, in graph_validate\n    result = configuration.metrics_validate(\n             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File \"/home/XXX/bordereaux/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/great_expectations/core/expectation_configuration.py\", line 1494, in metrics_validate\n    return expectation_impl(self).metrics_validate(\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File \"/home/XXX/bordereaux/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/great_expectations/expectations/expectation.py\", line 1100, in metrics_validate\n    ] = self._validate(\n        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\nTypeError: ExpectQueriedMulticolumnDureeInferieurUnAn._validate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'configuration'\n",
          "exception_message": "ExpectQueriedMulticolumnDureeInferieurUnAn._validate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'configuration'",
          "raised_exception": true
        }
      }
    ],

I will be very happy if anyone has an idea :)

It's good, I solved my problem, I specified in _validate() "configuration = None" and its works
